# Bash script csv manipulation optimization

Tags: bash, csv

I have a 2 million line csv file where what I want to do is replace the second column of each line in the csv file with a unique value to that string, these are all filled with usernames. The long process I've got below does work, but does take a while.

It doesn't have to be hashed, but this seemed like a sure way of when the next file comes along there are no discrepancies.

I'm by no means a coder, and was wondering if there was anyway that I could optimize the process. Although I understand the best way to do this would be in some sort of scripting language.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Enter Filename to Read
echo "Enter File Name"
read filename
#Extracts Usersnames from file
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' $filename > usernames.txt 
#Hashes Usernames using SHA256      
cat usernames.txt | while read line; do echo -n $line|openssl sha256 |sed      's/^.* //'; done > hashedusernames.txt
#Deletes usernames out of first file
cat hash.csv | cut -d, -f2 --complement > output.txt
#Pastes hashed usernames to end of first file
paste -d , output.txt hashedusernames.txt > output2.txt
#Moves everything back into place
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1","$4","$2","$3}' output2.txt > final.csv
```

Example File, there are 7 columns in all but only 3 are shown

```
Time Username Size
2017-01-01T14:53.45,Poke.callum,12345
2016-01-01T13:42.56,Test.User,54312
2015-01-01T12:34.34,Another.User,54123
```

Comment: Have you considered getting a distinct list of usernames, hashing those separately, and then joining back? Yes, a database and/or scripting language would probably be better suited for that.

Comment: Is this a recurring problem? Do you need to do it with the same file size all the time?

Comment: It can be done daily, on a much smaller file. It all gets fed into an ELK stack after but it may still need to be used on files this size again.

Comment: Well if it works the way it is, that's fine. But you could certainly also do it in a script. I've written up a Perl solution and will post it.

Comment: Becuase the information relates to the next 4 columns I dont think that process would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in Perl easily in a few lines. The following program uses the [Crypt::Digest::SHA256](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::Digest::SHA256), which you need to install from CPAN or from your OS repository if they have it.

The program assumes input from the `DATA` section, which we typically do around here to include example data in an mcve.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::Digest::SHA256 'sha256_b64u';

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    # no need to chomp because we don't touch the last line
    my @fields = split /,/, $line;
    $fields[1] = sha256_b64u($fields[1]);
    print join ',', @fields;
}

__DATA__
2017-01-01T14:53.45,Poke.callum,12345
2016-01-01T13:42.56,Test.User,54312
2015-01-01T12:34.34,Another.User,54123
```

It prints the following output.

```
2017-01-01T14:53.45,g8EPHWc3L1ln_lfRhq8elyOUgsiJm6BtTtb_GVt945s,12345
2016-01-01T13:42.56,jwXsws2dJq9h_R08zgSIPhufQHr8Au8_RmniTQbEKY4,54312
2015-01-01T12:34.34,mkrKXbM1ZiPiXSSnWYNo13CUyzMF5cdP2SxHGyO7rgQ,54123
```

To make it read a file that is supplied as a command line argument and write to a new file with the `.new` extension, you can use it like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::Digest::SHA256 'sha256_b64u';

open my $fh_in, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
open my $fh_out, '>', "$ARGV[0].new" or die $!;

while (my $line = <$fh_in>) {
    # no need to chomp because we don't touch the last line
    my @fields = split /,/, $line;
    $fields[1] = sha256_b64u($fields[1]);
    print $fh_out join ',', @fields;
}
```

Run it as follows:

$ perl foo.pl example.csv

Your new file will be named `example.csv.new`.

Comment: Thankyou, I imagine this will work perfectly Ill give it a test when i can find all installers to get the perl module working

Answer (score 1):

Yet another Python solution, focus on speed but also on maintainability.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import hashlib
import re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='CSV swaper')
parser.add_argument(
    '-f',
    '--file',
    dest='file_path',
    type=str,
    required=True,
    help='The CSV file path.')

def hash_user(users, user):
    try:
        return users[user]
    except KeyError:
        id_ = int(hashlib.md5(user.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16)
        users[user] = id_
        return id_
def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()
    username_extractor = re.compile(r',([\s\S]*?),')
    users = {}
    counter = 0
    templ = ',{},'
    with open(args.file_path) as file:
        with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
            line = file.readline()
            while line:
                try:
                    counter += 1
                    if counter == 1:
                        continue
                    username = username_extractor.search(line).groups()[0]
                    hashuser = hash_user(users, username)
                    output.write(username_extractor.sub(
                        templ.format(hashuser), line)
                    )
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                except:
                    print('Malformed line at {}'.format(counter))
                finally:
                    line = file.readline()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There are still some points that could be optimized, but the central ones are based on do `try` instead of check, and save users hashes in the case there are repeated users will not have to redigest the username.

Also, will You run this on a multi-core host?.. this can be easily be improved using threads.

Comment: Unfortunatly this hashes every second column, not just the second one overall

Comment: It will be on a multi core machine

Comment: I didn't understand the comment about the second column, can you detail it please?. And I can transform this script to use multi-core power once the core logic is ok.

Comment: If you meat about the Regex with the "Every Second Column", you miss two thins, one I use "search" instead of "findAll", second I limit the results to the first one in `...groups()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

This Python program might do what you want. You can pass the filenames to convert on the command line:

```
$ python this_program.py file1.csv file2.csv
```

```
import fileinput
import csv
import sys
import hashlib


class stdout:
    def write(self, *args):
        sys.stdout.write(*args)

input = fileinput.input(inplace=True, backup=".bak", mode='rb')
reader = csv.reader(input)
writer = csv.writer(stdout())

for row in reader:
    row[1] = hashlib.sha256(row[1]).hexdigest()
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `awk` in your original attempt, here's a simpler approach in `awk`

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{i=0;}
           {if (unique_names[$2] == "") {
                unique_names[$2]="Unique"i;
                i++;
            }
            $2=unique_names[$2];
            print $0}'
```